# How to run pgloader by skipping indexes?

Tags: postgresql, pgloader

Is it possible to run pgloader so that it excludes indexes? I can always create the indexes at the end when the entire process finishes.

My database is like 10GB and I am getting a heap exhausted error:

```
Heap exhausted during garbage collection: 576 bytes available, 2288 requested.
```

I am using the command:

pgloader mysql://root:@localhost/mydb postgresql:///mydbpsql